# Javascript, calendar source code

Tags: javascript

I am actually using this calendar source code, but I did encountered a problem which is, I wasn't able to display today's date and instead, I got back 'November ??110' What's wrong?!

Below are the codes...

```
//  SET ARRAYS
var day_of_week = new Array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
var month_of_year = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

//  DECLARE AND INITIALIZE VARIABLES
var Calendar = new Date();

var year = Calendar.getYear();      // Returns year
var month = Calendar.getMonth();    // Returns month (0-11)
var today = Calendar.getDate();    // Returns day (1-31)
var weekday = Calendar.getDay();    // Returns day (1-31)

var DAYS_OF_WEEK = 7;    // "constant" for number of days in a week
var DAYS_OF_MONTH = 31;    // "constant" for number of days in a month
var cal;    // Used for printing

Calendar.setDate(1);    // Start the calendar day at '1'
Calendar.setMonth(month);    // Start the calendar month at now


/* VARIABLES FOR FORMATTING
NOTE: You can format the 'BORDER', 'BGCOLOR', 'CELLPADDING', 'BORDERCOLOR'
      tags to customize your caledanr's look. */

var TR_start = '<TR>';
var TR_end = '</TR>';
var highlight_start = '<TD WIDTH="30"><TABLE CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=1 BGCOLOR=DEDEFF BORDERCOLOR=CCCCCC><TR><TD WIDTH=20><B><CENTER>';
var highlight_end   = '</CENTER></TD></TR></TABLE></B>';
var TD_start = '<TD WIDTH="30"><CENTER>';
var TD_end = '</CENTER></TD>';

/* BEGIN CODE FOR CALENDAR
NOTE: You can format the 'BORDER', 'BGCOLOR', 'CELLPADDING', 'BORDERCOLOR'
tags to customize your calendar's look.*/

cal =  '<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 BORDERCOLOR=BBBBBB><TR><TD>';
cal += '<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=2>' + TR_start;
cal += '<TD COLSPAN="' + DAYS_OF_WEEK + '" BGCOLOR="#EFEFEF"><CENTER><B>';
cal += month_of_year[month]  + ' ??' + year + '</B>' + TD_end + TR_end;
cal += TR_start;

//   DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS POINT  //

// LOOPS FOR EACH DAY OF WEEK
for(index=0; index < DAYS_OF_WEEK; index++)
{

// BOLD TODAY'S DAY OF WEEK
if(weekday == index)
cal += TD_start + '<B>' + day_of_week[index] + '</B>' + TD_end;

// PRINTS DAY
else
cal += TD_start + day_of_week[index] + TD_end;
}

cal += TD_end + TR_end;
cal += TR_start;

// FILL IN BLANK GAPS UNTIL TODAY'S DAY
for(index=0; index < Calendar.getDay(); index++)
cal += TD_start + '' + TD_end;

// LOOPS FOR EACH DAY IN CALENDAR
for(index=0; index < DAYS_OF_MONTH; index++)
{
if( Calendar.getDate() > index )
{
  // RETURNS THE NEXT DAY TO PRINT
  week_day =Calendar.getDay();

  // START NEW ROW FOR FIRST DAY OF WEEK
  if(week_day == 0)
  cal += TR_start;

  if(week_day != DAYS_OF_WEEK)
  {

  // SET VARIABLE INSIDE LOOP FOR INCREMENTING PURPOSES
  var day  = Calendar.getDate();

  // HIGHLIGHT TODAY'S DATE
  if( today==Calendar.getDate() )
  cal += highlight_start + day + highlight_end + TD_end;

  // PRINTS DAY
  else
  cal += TD_start + day + TD_end;
  }

  // END ROW FOR LAST DAY OF WEEK
  if(week_day == DAYS_OF_WEEK)
  cal += TR_end;
  }

  // INCREMENTS UNTIL END OF THE MONTH
  Calendar.setDate(Calendar.getDate()+1);

}// end for loop

cal += '</TD></TR></TABLE></TABLE>';

//  PRINT CALENDAR
document.write(cal);

//  End -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Date.getYear` method is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) because of Y2K reasons and behaves differently in Firefox (*e.g.* 110) and Internet Explorer (*e.g.* 2010) for dates after 1999. Use `Date.getFullYear()` instead, which [will always return a four-digit year](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear).

To get rid of the question marks, just remove the question marks in this line:

```
cal += month_of_year[month]  + ' ??' + year + '</B>' + TD_end + TR_end;
```